# How to handle overlay in angular using selenium webdriver and select multiple values (coming from excel) from dropdowns

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, overlay

I want to select multiple values from the dropdown using webdriver. The values will be fetched from excel file. Two issues faced while trying to automate this

1. Since two different dropdowns are next to each other, there is a problem with overlay. Once I click on the first dropdown and select a value, and then try to click on the next dropdowns to select a value from it, below error gets thrown. How to avoid this?
2. How to import multiple values that are to be selected from the dropdowns?
   `org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <mat-select _ngcontent-lkq-c113="" role="listbox" formcontrolname="Location" multiple="" class="mat-select ng-tns-c62-9 ng-tns-c47-8 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" id="mat-select-1" tabindex="0" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-multiselectable="true">...</mat-select> is not clickable at point (689, 189). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div>(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)`

Goal is to select these dropdowns and click on search button. I could select these forcefully using Javascript "jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);" and get the results but need an alternative solution. Please suggest.

Comment: ever make any progress?